# Endless circular redirect with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm developing multi-tenant ASP.NET MVC application using **Finbuckle.Multitenant** and **IdentityServer4** (using standard classes and controllers from their tutorials). My app uses route strategy for tenants (https://host/tenant1/controller/action) and I use separate cookies for each tenant (cookie named *auth.tenant1*, *auth.tenant2*... etc.) Everything works fine unless I specify custom Path for auth cookie. If all of them has *Path=/* everything is ok. BUT when I set *Path=/tenant1* to cookie named auth.tenant1 and the same pattern for every other tenants I have a circular redirects after passing consent screen. When I click "yes" on consent screen I got 302 challenge redirect from IdentityServer middleware on client side. It redirects me back to Consent screen. After each "yes" I'm returning to consent. However it happens only during authentication process. If I open new tab and head to https://host/tenant1 I won't be redirected and will be successfully authenticated.
Googled for answers for days but haven't found any solutions. Please help me!

Here is my client's **Startup.cs**:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddMultiTenant().WithInMemoryStore(Configuration.GetSection("MultiTenant:InMemoryStore"))
            .WithRouteStrategy(MapRoutes)
            .WithRemoteAuthentication()
            .WithPerTenantOptions<AuthenticationOptions>((options, tenantContext) =>
            {
                // Allow each tenant to have a different default challenge scheme.
                if (tenantContext.Items.TryGetValue("ChallengeScheme", out object challengeScheme))
                {
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = (string)challengeScheme;
                }
            })
            .WithPerTenantOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>((options, tenantContext) =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name += tenantContext.Identifier;
                options.Cookie.Path = "/" + tenantContext.Identifier;
                options.LoginPath = "/" + tenantContext.Identifier + "/Home/Login";
            });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = "auth.";
            })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            //Hybrid protocols (OpenId + OAuth)
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            //ask to allow access to testApi
            options.Scope.Add("testApi");
            //allows requesting refresh tokens for long lived API access
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                {
                    var tenant = ctx.HttpContext.GetMultiTenantContext()?.TenantInfo?.Identifier;
                    ctx.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = $"tenant:{tenant}";
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });
    }

    private void MapRoutes(IRouteBuilder router)
    {
        router.MapRoute("Default", "{__tenant__=tenant1}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    }
```

Here is my client configuration on IdentityServer's side (appsettings.json):

```
{
  "clientId": "mvc",
  "clientName": "MVC Client",
  "allowedGrantTypes": [ "hybrid", "client_credentials" ],
  "clientSecrets": [
    { "value": "K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=" } // Sha256("secret")
  ],
  "redirectUris": [ "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" ],
  "postLogoutRedirectUris": [ "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" ],
  "allowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "testApi" ],
  "allowOfflineAccess": true
},
```

My IdentityServer4 config:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        if (_config.GetSection("AppSettings:UseDummyAuthentication").Get<bool>())
        {
            identityServerBuilder
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(_config.GetSection("IdentityResources"))
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(_config.GetSection("ApiResources"))
                .AddInMemoryClients(_config.GetSection("Clients"))
                .AddTestUsers(_config.GetSection("TestUsers"));
        }

        services.AddAuthentication();
    }
```

Please help me, guys! How can I make Path=/tenant1 scheme work without redirects on consent screen???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what's wrong and post answer to those who will encounter the same problem. The problem is that when you change Path of cookie IdentityServer's middleware can't find it because it hosted on https://host/signin-oidc/. What you need to handle this is https://host/tenant1/signin-oidc for each of your tenant on client and add all those urls to clients redirectUris.
To achieve it your multitenant configuration should look like this

```
            services.AddMultiTenant().WithInMemoryStore(Configuration.GetSection("MultiTenant:InMemoryStore"))
            .WithRouteStrategy(MapRoutes)
            .WithRemoteAuthentication()
            .WithPerTenantOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>((options, tenantContext) =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = $"auth.{tenantContext.Identifier}";
                options.Cookie.Path = "/" + tenantContext.Identifier;
                options.LoginPath = "/" + tenantContext.Identifier + "/Home/Login";
            })
            .WithPerTenantOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>((opt, ctx) =>
            {
                opt.CallbackPath = "/" + ctx.Identifier + "/signin-oidc";
            });
```

**Whole Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddMultiTenant().WithInMemoryStore(Configuration.GetSection("MultiTenant:InMemoryStore"))
            .WithRouteStrategy(MapRoutes)
            .WithRemoteAuthentication()
            .WithPerTenantOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>((options, tenantContext) =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = $"auth.{tenantContext.Identifier}";
                options.Cookie.Path = "/" + tenantContext.Identifier;
                options.LoginPath = "/" + tenantContext.Identifier + "/Home/Login";
            })
            .WithPerTenantOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>((opt, ctx) =>
            {
                opt.CallbackPath = "/" + ctx.Identifier + "/signin-oidc";
            }); ;

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = "auth.";
                o.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";

            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            //Hybrid protocols (OpenId + OAuth)
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            //ask to allow access to testApi
            options.Scope.Add("testApi");
            //allows requesting refresh tokens for long lived API access
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                {
                    var tenant = ctx.HttpContext.GetMultiTenantContext()?.TenantInfo?.Identifier;
                    ctx.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = $"tenant:{tenant}";
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            var errorPage = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ErrorPage");
            app.UseExceptionHandler(errorPage);
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMultiTenant();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(MapRoutes);
    }

    private void MapRoutes(IRouteBuilder router)
    {
        router.MapRoute("Default", "{__tenant__=tenant1}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    }
```

Don't forget to register all tenants urls in IdentityServer4 **Client.RedirecUris**

```
"redirectUris": [ "https://localhost:5002/tenant1/signin-oidc", "https://localhost:5002/tenant2/signin-oidc", "https://localhost:5002/tenant3/signin-oidc" ]
```

Comment: Hi. I am using the same approach as you did but I am stuck on one point. When I try to access tenant1, system redirect me towards identity service (implemented by IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Core Identity framework) login page. After successful login, it redirect me back towards MVC application. Now when i try to access another tenant e.g. tenant2, it redirects me towards "Authorize" end point of identity server. It is actually using asp.net core identity cookie to redirect user towards authorize end point. Can you please help me how can land user to Login page?

Comment: Hi, @BilalHashmi 
Hard to say without code, but I think after accessing tenant2 your user should be redirected on the consent screen. Once allowed tenant2 should be allowed without consent screen. It's a normal behavior, I think user shouldn't login every time. But if you want so, you should work with your session cookie. It should be tenant domain specific. Please have a look in that direction

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have fixed that issue by listening an event (OnValidatePrincipal) on identity cookie options at IdentityServer4 end. In event handler, I compare the user associated tenant and tenant info received in acr_values. In case of mismatch, I reject the principal.

Comment: @BilalHashmi great :)